Dual Boot....Want to Move totally over to Ubuntu
I came back to linux and I dual boot windows/Ubuntu.  On my laptop. After some months , I want to move totally over to Ubuntu. Is there a way I can , delete everything windows on my laptop, without going through the process of a complete reinstall? I have everything set up on my laptop so far how I want it. I want to keep everything Ubuntu on my laptop and get rid of everything windows on it. Thank you for any responses and replies and your Time.
It is unbuntu desktop.Windows was installed first. I have two HDs.



Open the app gparted. Install it in Ubuntu if not installed. Take a screenshot of the drive with Windows and Ubuntu. Edit the question above and add the screenshot. Explain (figure out) what each of the positions are for. Once you know that, you will know which ones to delete.

I'd ensure your Ubuntu system is controlling the boot process (you didn't specify if using uEFI or another legacy system), then its pretty safe to delete the unwanted system (windows etc). You'll need to boot live if you wish to expand (increase in size) your existing Ubuntu partitions to utilize the unused space, OR you can just partition it however you want as additional space (You didn't provide specifics; Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? nor what release etc so we don't know much currently).

ok, thank you . its unbuntu desktop. windows was on the laptop first. I will work , and invesitgate more ..and return. Thank everyone for responses.
